# Apache Server .htaccess rewrite with wildcard

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Is it possible to create a rewrite code that includes a wildcard?

for example any request for:

```
 http://example.com/something1/something2/*
```

would redirect to:

```
 http://example.com/newthing
```

AND

will it matter where in the .htaccess file I place the rewrites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^something1/something2/(.*)$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

It should change `http://example.com/something1/something2/test` to `http://example.com/test`

EDIT:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shirts/(.*)$ /clothing.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks! The client just changed their request.

How would I change it from
    http://example.com/shirts/*
    http://example.com/clothing

Comment: hmm.

exmample.com/shirts/*  ---now redirects to--- example.com/clothing.html/*  (with the rest of the url duplicating what would have been after /shirts/ in the original url

Comment: You don't the rest of the url after `clothing/`?

Comment: not sure what you are asking.

The goal is broad redirect such that all requests that begin with example.com/shirts  will dump to example.com/clothing.html  -- thanks for your help btw

Comment: Okay, change `clothing/$1` to `clothing.html`.

Comment: same results.  does it matter where in the file I place it?

Comment: So going to `example.com/shirts/something` will direct you to `example.com/clothing.html/something`?

Comment: yes-- actually to example.com/clothing.html/something/something2/something3 etc

Comment: Have you any other rewrite rules in your htaccess? Can you try another browser?

Comment: SOLVED: I moved the rewrite to the top of the file and now it works like a charm.  --thanks!